# How to keep a <div> tag inside a <div> when moving in Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a problem on keeping a `<div>` inside a `<div>`. One of them moves, but if it goes too far, it goes out of the big one and the page. I am using Jquery to animate the `<div>`.  **Note:**  The  little `<div>` moves horizontally.

Properties:
Big `<div>`:
Width: 600px

`#truck` is the little `<div>`.

My code(Jquery):

```
     function moveRight(){
     $('#truck').animate({
     'marginLeft' : "+=3px"
     });
     }
     function moveLeft(){
     $('#truck').animate({
     'marginLeft' : "-=3px" 
     });
     }//later code<br>
     window.addEventListener('keydown', function(evt){
     var key = evt.keyCode;
     if( key == 39){
     moveRight() = true;
     moveLeft() = false;
     }
     if( key == 37){
     moveLeft() = true;
     moveRight() = false;
     }

     }, false);
```

Please help!
There is no jsfiddle but I have google apis jquery.

Comment: can you post a working example? Or at the very least your HTML & CSS?

Comment: Tidy up your code and please add a snippet or jsfiddle.

Answer (score 0):

can not give an exact answer without looking at HTML & CSS. 
but as I think

```
'marginLeft' : "-=3px"
```

when this line is executed, if the value of the margin-left get a negative value then inner `<div>` will go out  of the range of outer `<div>`.

Same thing can be happened when below line is executed,

```
'marginLeft' : "+=3px
```

if the margin-left value is greater than the width of the outer `<div>`, even then inner `<div>` will go out of the range of outer `<div>`

Answer (score 0):

You can check if your `truck`'s `margin-left` is below zero or beyond your container's width.

```js
function moveRight() {
  var left = $('#truck').css("marginLeft").match(/\d+/g);
  if (left < 320) {
    $('#truck').animate({
      'marginLeft': "+=80px"
    });
  }
}

function moveLeft() {
    var left = $('#truck').css("marginLeft").match(/\d+/g);
    if (left >= 80) {
      $('#truck').animate({
        'marginLeft': "-=80px"
      });
    }
  } //later code<br>
window.addEventListener('keydown', function(evt) {
  var key = evt.keyCode;
  if (key == 39) {
    moveRight() = true;
    moveLeft() = false;
  }
  if (key == 37) {
    moveLeft() = true;
    moveRight() = false;
  }

}, false);
```

```css
#container {
  width: 400px;
  height: 40px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
#truck {
  margin-left: 0px;
  width: 80px;
  height: 40px;
  background-color: #AAA;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">
  <div id="truck"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: I just used canvas HTML.